# How to get the name of goal in maven2's Mojo at runtime

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, mojo

For Maven2 how can I get the name of goal currently being executed in Mojo's execute method? Precisely I need value of @goal attribute inside Mojo's execute method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getGoalName(PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor, String mojoClassName) {
        String goalName=null;
        List<MojoDescriptor> mojoDescriptorList = pluginDescriptor.getMojos();
        for (MojoDescriptor mojoDescriptor : mojoDescriptorList) {
            if (mojoDescriptor.getImplementation().equals(mojoClassName)) {
                goalName=mojoDescriptor.getGoal();
                break;
            }
        }
        return goalName;
    }
```

Here, PluginDescriptor can be fetched from pluginManager.getPluginDescriptorForPrefix("prefix-for-your-plugin"). PluginManager is available as @component role="org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManager"

Comment: I have used this solution with great success on maven2, but when i switched to maven3 it stopped working. In maven3 it gets the **mojoDescriptorList** for the latest version in the maven repository, and not the version I'm using. So if you have removed a goal in the newest version of your plugin, and you use an older plugin, **mojoDescriptorList** will be missing a goal that is still present in the old version of the plugin.